# Accordion for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

Is there a accordion control for Xamarin Forms? I want to place static content in each accordion. 
I am visualizing something similar to this?

```
<control:Accordian>
   <control:Accordian.Items>
      <AccordionItem HeaderTitle="step 1">
         <Label Text="This is step1" />
      </AccordionItem>
      <AccordionItem  HeaderTitle="step 2">
         <Label Text="This is step 2" />
      </AccordionItem>
      <AccordionItem  HeaderTitle="step 3">
         <Label Text="This is step 3" />
      </AccordionItem>
   </control:Accordian.Items>
</control:Accordian>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a default control in Xamarin.Forms. A sample implementation by S Ravi-Kumar can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088093/Simple-Accordion-User-Control-in-Xamarin-Forms) and the source code [here](https://github.com/srkrathore/AccordionEx). Running it will look like this:

[image: Accordion control on iOS]